# "Python.h" file not found on MACOSX, how to fix this?

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, pyaudio

`pip3 install PyAudio==0.2.12
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting PyAudio==0.2.12
Using cached PyAudio-0.2.12.tar.gz (42 kB)
Installing build dependencies ... done
Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: PyAudio
Building wheel for PyAudio (pyproject.toml) ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Building wheel for PyAudio (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [16 lines of output]
running bdist_wheel
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39
copying src/pyaudio.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39
running build_ext
building '_portaudio' extension
creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39
creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39/src
clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -iwithsysroot/System/Library/Frameworks/System.framework/PrivateHeaders -iwithsysroot/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/Headers -arch arm64 -arch x86_64 -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -DMACOSX=1 -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/Headers -c src/_portaudiomodule.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39/src/_portaudiomodule.o
src/_portaudiomodule.c:30:10: fatal error: 'Python.h' file not found
#include "Python.h"
^~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit code 1
[end of output]

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
ERROR: Failed building wheel for PyAudio
Failed to build PyAudio
ERROR: Could not build wheels for PyAudio, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects`

I want to use the speech recognition module. I downloaded `portaudio` via `homebrew`, but I am unable to download `pyaudio`.

Comment: Brew install python3.9-devel ... Or something similar

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 11):

Export these  from the command line terminal but change the path to be your correct path, then try again from the same command line terminal

```
export CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/Headers
export C_INCLUDE_PATH=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/Headers
```

Comment: This saved me tones of time! I got the headers from `xcode-select --install` command line tools & generalized the export version to whatever system `Current` is. Then made `pycharm` project define these.